# How to display a boolean value using FormGroup?

Tags: angular

How to display a value with type boolean? I use FormGroup to track values. But when I try to display a field with the type checkbox (boolean), nothing appears (void).

ts:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      is_active: new FormControl(false)
    })
  }
```

html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <label>
          <input formControlName="is_active" id="is_active" type="checkbox"  class="filled-in">
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: @SunilSingh No i don't get

Comment: Do you see the checkbox at least ?

Comment: I copy pasted your code and it works fine with a checkbox bound to formControl. There must be an error somewhere else.

Comment: @SunilSingh I do not see the checkbox at all

Comment: Then there is issue with your css.  Remove all css class specially for `<div class="input-field col s12">` and then check.

Comment: @SunilSingh Deleted already, made simply `<input formControlName =" is_active "id =" is_active "type =" checkbox ">` doesn't see anyway for some reason

Comment: what do you want to display? @user10493107, A checkbox and then its text?

Comment: display checkbox

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not angular but materializecss,

From the class name you are using i guess you are using [materializecss](https://materializecss.com/checkboxes.html/%22%22) the correct syntax for checkbox in materializecss is

```
    <label>
       <input type="checkbox" />
       <span>Red</span>
    </label>
```

the span which now becomes the label and must always be included, so if you don't want it to have any label you can just leave an empty span tag there like this,

```
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span></span>
     </label>
```

Comment: it does not help i found another way to fix it

Comment: are you using materializecss?

Comment: yes, but I fixed it like this <mat-checkbox formControlName = "is_active"> Active </ mat-checkbox>